# Why WordPress convert my webP images into JPG?

Tags: images

ENVIRONMENT: WP Version 6.4.1

When I want to upload a webp image in my woocommerce product, WordPress converts my webP image into JPG.

So I deactivated all the plugins and tried to upload my webP from the Media Manager => I got the same issue.

I activated another theme to check if it was my theme source of this issue, but I got the same issue with other themes.

This is weird as it was working fine before.

Does anyone have this issue? How can I fix that?

Comment: note that there are posts on the Make WP official blogs about webp that explain what they wanted to do, why they had to do this, how to work around it, and why they couldn't serve webp originally, this isn't a theme/plugin problem and it's deliberate

Comment: see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52867, making it generate webp files for the intermediate size files is not as straight forward a task as it might seem, lots of caveats and edge cases, whatever WP does has to work for everybody